# Is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}E[X_n] = 0$ if $X_n\to 0$ in probability?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Is there any counter example that:

Let $X_1, X_2,\dots$ be a sequence of random variables that converge to $0$ in probability. That is, for any $c > 0$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|X_n - 0| > c) = 0$$

Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}E[X_n] = 0$ ?

Comment: If your sequence of random variables converges in probability AND is uniformly integrable, then you can conclude convergence of expectation.

Answer (score 3):

Take $X_n:=n\chi_{(0,n^{—1})}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not even true if you assume all the expectations exist!  There need to be some uniform boundedness also.